# Rails many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following situation that seems like it should be easy in Rails but it's escaping me.  Lets say I have the following many to many relationship.  A user and groups (group being something a user belongs to through a 'membership'):

```
  Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups, through: :memberships
  end

  Class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :users
    belongs_to :groups
  end

  Class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: :memberships
  end
```

So now I do a query that selects more than one group (so i would get an array of groups that were, as an example, in the Northeast region.  Something like this:

```
northeast_groups = Group.where("region = 'northeast'")
```

Now what I would like to do is something like this:

```
northeast_groups.users.count
```

or better yet, something like this:

```
northeast_groups.users.each do |u|
```

to loop through all of the users for the selected groups.

Is there a way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
User.includes(:groups).where(groups: { region: 'northeast' })
```

**Attention:**

You have to use the relation's name in the `includes` and `joins`, but you have to use the exact table's name in the `where` clause:

```
User has_many :posts
#              ^^^^^
Post belongs_to :user
#                ^^^^

User.includes(:posts).where(posts: { title: 'Little bobby table' })
#              ^^^^^        ^^^^^
Post.includes(:user).where(users: { username: 'Bob' })
#              ^^^^        ^^^^^
```